# modal load in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to load modal automatically on page load and the modal would close and reopen `onclick`. I have put following command to automatically load modal `modal.open();` This loaded my modal automatically on page load. Later I have used following to close the modal on button click:

```
function onClick() { 
    if (modal.isOpen) {
       close(); 
    }
 }
```

This one is working too. But now, I want to load the modal again by clicking the button which is not working. When I am placing

```
openButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  modal.open();
});
```

instead of `modal.open();` the modal is loading on every alternative click and closing on other clicks. But in this scenario, I am not getting automatically loading of modal on page load.

Comment: Could you please create a demo replicating your problem.

Comment: you need to add jquery library. than add the below code $(document).ready(function(){ modal.open();});

Comment: You cant load a modal, you can only open it.

Comment: Many things could be happened. Where have you wrote `openButton.addEventListener(...`? Any error in console log? Please make a minimum fiddle.